# xsl variable inside javascript which is in a XSL file itself

Tags: javascript, xslt, variables

is it possible to add xsl variable inside javascript which itself is inside xsl template..basically there are two radio buttons 'classes' and 'events', a textbox and Search button. so when a user selects one of the radios and type in a keyword in textbox, i wanna be able to pull only those values related to the selected radio..is this even possible?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                                <![CDATA[
                                    var selected_radio = $("input[name='EventRadio']:checked").val();
                                    if (selected_radio == 'Classes') 
                                        {
                                            <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[XPATH to get only the selected radio related data]       
                                        }
                                 ]]>
                            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**A CDATA section is just part of a text node and as such is just a one-dimensional string** -- anything in this string that looks like markup (such as an `<xsl:variable>`) is just this -- string, text.

**Therefore, including XSLT instructions inside a CDATA sections does not cause this string to be parsed and interpreted as XSLT instructions**.

**What is possible, is to invoke a new XSLT transformation from the Javascript code** and to pass as external parameter(s) to the transformation any user-entered data that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you are confused about the processing model. The XSLT code is generating an HTML page containing lots of elements, one of which is a script element. When it's done its job, the browser loads the HTML page and executes the onLoad javascript contained in the HTML page. The XSLT code by this stage has terminated, and nothing you do in the Javascript can possibly affect the execution of the XSLT.

For a more interactive processing model, consider playing with Saxon-CE, which allows user interaction events to be processed by XSLT templates.